# Firebase query slow code execution: append to table

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was hoping I could get some help optimising my code. I´m new to development so please be kind.

Currently it works, but it uses quite some time (10-15 sec) to load the first table view I need in my app. 
First I thought that I had not activated "persistence" properly, but I am starting to suspect that it is the way I am loading data that is suboptimal.

The "large" (12k + items) data set I use dont change that frequently, so the ideal solution would be to load that once, then listen for changes. I thought that was what I am doing, but if so I dont understand why it is so slow? So I now suspect that it is the way that I append the data every time, instead of just "reading/loading" from "somewhere local" and then listen for changes from the sever?

Any help is appreciated

```
//read From Firebase adjusted to whiskies
func startObservingDB ()  {
    dbRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "brand_name").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
        var newWhisky = [WhiskyItem]()

        //forloop to iterate through the snapshot

        for whiskyItem in snapshot.children {
            let whiskyObject = WhiskyItem(snapshot: whiskyItem as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newWhisky.append(whiskyObject)
        }

        //update
        self.whiskies = newWhisky
        print("WhiskyItem")
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error: Error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Firebase structure: /Results/Index/name: xxx, "other thing1": xxxx,..., "other thing32": xxxx

Comment: You're looking for something called Pagination.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, that it is a good idea to store all 12 000 items on your phone.

May be it will be good solution for you:

You can use this [lib](https://github.com/eggswift/pull-to-refresh) for:

(example)

1) load data for 100 rows

2) scroll to the end

3) do another load of 100 rows.

Hope it helps